# clojure Alphanumeric sorting

Tags: sorting, clojure

I can sort alphabets or numbers using sort but how do I sort a mixture of alphabets and numbers.

```
(sort ["f" "g" "a" "b" "c"]) ; ==> ("a" "b" "c" "f" "g")

(sort [3 4 6 1 8 ])  ; ==> (1 3 4 6 8)
```

Question is, how do I sort this? `["g" "a" "c" 4 6 1]` to get `(1 4 6 "a" "c" "g")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot compare a number and a string.

```
=> (sort ["g" "a" "c" 4 6 1])
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

So to do what you want, you have to convert the numbers to strings then sort. For example:

```
=> (sort (map str ["g" "a" "c" 4 6 1]))
("1" "4" "6" "a" "c" "g")
```

Comment: @D-side Nice, didn't know about `sort-by`, thanks! I think it's definitely better and deserves its own answer for sure.

Comment: Yeah, thought that too and wiped my comment for that reason. WIP =)

Comment: I think [D-side answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31585978/898478) is a better one.

Answer (score 14):

The main issue is that you cannot compare a string with a number in a generic way: these are different types of values. When someone says "what's better: an apple or a house?", the first question that could probably pop into one's mind is "better in what way?" You can sort these two objects by many different properties, like size, cost or edibility. `sort` does not make the call about what property to use.

That's where [`sort-by` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sort-by) comes in. First it takes a `keyfn`, that when called on any element should produce its comparable property: in our case it's a string representation of a given element. Then it takes a collection, then (optionally) a comparator.

So you use **`str`** as your `keyfn` and you don't need a comparator, since comparison of strings is well-defined.

The resulting code is plain and simple:

```
(sort-by str ["g" "a" "c" 4 6 1]) ; => (1 4 6 "a" "c" "g")
```